# problemas con el siguiente método de dos dimensiones

Tags: java

Que tal compañeros tengo algunos problemas con este ejercicio, no llevo mucho tiempo en esto de la programación, este es el enunciado:

Enunciado
Escriba un método que indique cuál es la tendencia de color de la imagen. Un píxel tiene un color de tendencia roja, si su índice es mayor que los otros dos. Lo mismo sucede con los demás colores. Este método retorna 0 si la imagen no tiene ninguna tendencia, 1 si la tendencia es roja, 2 si la tendencia es verde y 3 si la tendencia es azul.

- Retorna la tendencia de color de la imagen. Un pixel tiene un color de tendencia roja si su índice es mayor que los otros dos; lo mismo
- sucede para los otros componentes. La tendencia de color de la imagen está definida entonces como el componente que tenga más pixeles con tendencia a ese color.
- @return - Tendencia de color de la imagen. Los posibles valores son:
- 0 si la imagen no presenta ninguna tendencia
- 1 si la tendencia es roja
- 2 si la tendencia es verde
- 3 si la tendencia es azul
  */

Este es mi codigo:

```
   public int calcularTendencia()
{
    int red = 0;
    int green = 0;
    int blue = 0;
    int ninguna = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < alto; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < ancho; j++)
        {
            Color actual = bitmap[i][j];

            if((actual.getRed()>actual.getGreen())&&(actual.getRed()>actual.getBlue()))
            {
                red++;
            }
            else if((actual.getGreen()>actual.getRed())&&(actual.getGreen()>actual.getBlue()))
            {
                green++;
            }
            else if((actual.getBlue()>actual.getRed())&&(actual.getBlue()>actual.getGreen()))
            {
                blue++;
            }
            else
            {
                ninguna++;
            }
        }
    }    
    if((red > green)&&(red > blue))
    {
        red = 1;
        return red;
    }
    else if((green > red)&&(green > blue))
    {
        green = 2;
        return green;
    }
    else if((blue > red)&&(blue > green))
    {
        blue = 3;
        return green;
    }
    else
    {
        return ninguna;
    }


}
```

Esto me arroja el siguiente error:

La tendencia no se calcula correctamente. Se esperaba 3, pero usted respondió 0 
La tendencia no se calcula correctamente. Se esperaba 0, pero usted respondió 120000

Aqui dejo el diagrama de clases:

https://cupiexamenes.virtual.uniandes.edu.co/media/web/modelos-mundo/15bc13c8598.jpg

gracias de antemano.

Comment: `else if((blue > red)&&(blue > green))
    {
        blue = 3;
        return green;
    }`

Comment: buenas noches podrías por favor enseñarme cómo quedó el código con las correcciones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Retorna 0 cuando se espera 3 porque en la comprobación final para determinar si la tendencia es azul, retornas el valor de la variable `green` en vez de retornar el valor de la variable `blue`:

```
else if((blue > red)&&(blue > green))
{
    blue = 3;
    return green;
}
```

lo correcto sería

```
else if((blue > red)&&(blue > green))
{
    blue = 3;
    return blue;
}
```

2 - Retorna 120000 cuando se espera 0, porque estás retornando el valor de la variable `ninguna` que toma valor dentro del ciclo que calcula la tendencia y no lo pones en 0 en las condicionales finales, como si haces con el resto de variables. Para evitar esto, al igual que el error anterior, te recomiendo que mejores un poco el código de las condicionales finales de la siguiente manera.

```
if((red > green)&&(red > blue))
    return 1;

if((green > red)&&(green > blue))
    return 2;

if((blue > red)&&(blue > green))
    return 3;

return ninguna;
```

Comment: No importa si las pruebas las tienes automatizadas con una herramienta o las haces tu manualmente, el par de problemas que tienes en el código provocan que no se obtengan los valores esperados.

Comment: Muchas gracias ese era el error. tendré en cuenta estos errores.